# Plant whose leaves turn to pink. What is it?

Tags: identification, houseplants

What is this flower plant that turns its leaves to bright pink? How do I care for it?

Location: Delhi.

[image]

Stem:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *Poinsettia* - they come in a range of colours, pink, white, red. If yours has produced these coloured bracts all on its own, the conditions must be right for it - in the UK, we buy red ones at Christmas and then throw them away, because getting them to produce red bracts again is a  performance, with the plant needing to be placed in darkness for a few weeks.

They like bright daylight, but not direct sun; they do not like to dry out, but the usual rules apply; water when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, water well, and allow excess to drain away freely. Further info here https://www.lowes.com/n/buying-guide/selecting-caring-poinsettia

Comment: To get bloom at a specific time, eg. Christmas, they must be grown in dedicated light controlled greenhouses ; they bloom according to light/dark cycle times.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Can you please expand on the bloom according to light cycle stuff?

Comment: They start to bloom when the daylight periods become longer and must have total darkness at night. There are several internet site that go into detail.

Answer (score 0):

Alternanthera ficoidea Party Time.  This plant does best in full sun to partial shade. It requires an evenly moist well-drained soil for optimal growth, but will die in standing water. It is not particular as to soil type or pH. It is highly tolerant of urban pollution and will even thrive in inner city environments. Consider applying a thick mulch around the root zone over the growing season to conserve soil moisture. This is a selected variety of a species not originally from North America. It can be propagated by cuttings; however, as a cultivated variety, be aware that it may be subject to certain restrictions or prohibitions on propagation.

Comment: It's not  Alternanthera  Party Time - that has mixed coloration on the leaves, not bracts all the same colour, though they are similar at first glance. Poinsettia and Alternantheria belong to different plant families.